# Instances: How to I return multiple parentheses like shown in the example?

Tags: java, eclipse

Add new Point instances to Path p and move the Path such that the String returned by this method is: "[(3,3)(2,2)(0,0)]"

```
public String p16Output() {
    Path p = new Path();
    // TODO
    return p.toString();
```

**I FIGURED IT OUT ON MY OWN**

Comment: build toString function. What is your try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a toString method and customize the way you want to build your string.

An example of this can be the following

```
 public String toString() {
    String s = "";
`//building the string you want to return like so 's = //How you want it.  '`

    return s;
```

}

Comment: Hit the check if that answered your question and you are welcome.